# Game of life continues bounds

Tags: c++

So I've been trying my hand at game of life and I noticed that the cells only stay confined within the grid that I've created. I want to try and make it continuous so if a cell reaches one side it will continue from the other side. Similar to the game pac-man when you leave from the left to come back into the game from the right side. Here is an image of how it would look as the cell moves out of bounds https://i.stack.imgur.com/dofv6.png

Here is the code that I have which confines everything. So How would I make it wrap back around?

```
int NeighborhoodSum(int i, int j) {
  int sum = 0;
  int k, l;
  for (k=i-1;k<=i+1;k++) {
    for (l=j-1;l<=j+1;l++) {
      if (k>=0 && k<gn && l>=0 && l<gm && !(k==i && l==j)) {
        sum+=current[k][l];
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Based on dshepherd suggestion this is what I have come up with.

```
if (!(k == i && l == j)) {
    sum += current[k][l];
} else if (k == 1 || k == -1) { // rows
    sum += current[k+1][l];
} else if (l == 1 || l == -1) { // columns
    sum += current[k][l+1];
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :-)

Comment: So, you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: @Kos haha I know I forgot to ask how to make it wrap back around :P

Comment: @PlasmaHH hints or point me in the right direction please

Comment: Why will no one help lol?

Comment: what do the variables stand for?  is k the x coord and l the y coord?  I could point you in the right direction if you can comment the above code to explain what its doing:)

Answer (score 1):

Start considering a one dimension array, of size ARRAY_SIZE.

What do you want that array to return when you ask for a cell of a negative index ? What about a for an index >= ARRAY_SIZE ? What operators does that make you think of (hint : <= 0, % ARRAY_SIZE, ...)

This will lead you to a more generic solution that dshepherd's one, for example if you want in the future to be able to specify life / death rules more than just one index around the cell.

Comment: Is it ? We will not do the work for you. Try to focus on **WHAT** you want to do, not **HOW** you will do it. The problem and its solution have to be clear in your head or on some paper / in a text editor **BEFORE** you start writing code. And when you write code, please NAME your variable according to the problem you're trying to solve : currentColumnIndex, columnCount, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a grid size of `0` to `n-1` for `x` and `0` to `m-1` for `y` (where `n` is the size of the `x` dimension and `m` is the size of the `y` dimension, what you want to do is check if the coordinates are in-range, and move accordingly.  So (pseudocode):

```
//  normal move calculation code here
if (x < 0)  {    x = n-1;  }
if (x >= n)  {    x = 0;  }
if (y < 0)  {    y = m-1;  }
if (y >= m)  {    y = 0;  }
//  carry out actual move here
```

With the start position marked as red, you need to calculate a movement into, or a breeding into, a new square: you need to check for whether it would fall out of bounds.  If it does then the new cell would be born in either of the orange positions, if not it could be born
 in any of the blue positions:

[image: Figure one: orange are overflow remapped positions, blue are non remapped "natural" positions]

Hope that helps:)  Let me know if you need more information though:)

Comment: I appreciate the help but is there another way you can explain this in more simple terms? Maybe visually? I've been at this for days and I've been struggling with it.

Comment: Iterating from 0 to n implies an array size of n + 1. If the size of the array is n, your cells should be indexed from 0 to n - 1..

Comment: you need to change your drawing as well ;)

Comment: Yep I changed them both at the same time:)  took me 4 refreshes in chrome though to see it lol

Comment: It seems that your drawing still indexes the cells from **1** to n - 1 instead of **0** to n - 1

Comment: erm it seems I was suffering from temporary stupidity, and while I changed the `n-1` end forgot to change the `1` end of the range!  Sorted now and cheers for your patience and corrections:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are taking a summation over nearest neighbours, so all you need to do to make it wrap around is to extend the summation to include the cells on the other side if `(i,j)` is an edge cell.

You could do this fairly easily by adding else statements to the central `if` to check for the cases where `l` or `k` are `-1` or `gn`/`gm` (i.e. just past the edges) and add the appropriate term from the cell on the opposite side.

Update:

What you've added in your edit is not what I meant, and I'm pretty sure it won't work. I think you need to carefully think through exactly what it is that the initial code does before you go any further. Maybe get some paper and do some example cases by hand?

More specific advice (but do what I said above before you try to use this):

1. You can't directly take `current[k][l]` if `k` or `l` are negative or greater than `gn`/`gm` respectively because there is no array entry with that index (the program should segfault). What you actually want it to do is use the `0`th entry anywhere that it would normally use the `gn`th entry, and so on for all the other boundaries.
2. You will probably need to split the if statement into 5 parts not 3 because the cases for `k < 0` and `k > gn` are different (similarly for `l`).
3. You are comparing against completely the wrong values with `(k == 1 || k == -1)` and similarly for `l`

Comment: I added to my post can you take a look please?